# replace substring of matched regex

Tags: java, regex, string, removing-whitespace

I fetch some html and do some string manipulation and en up with a string like

```
string sample = "\n    \n   2 \n      \n  \ndl. \n \n    \n flour\n\n     \n 4   \n    \n cups of    \n\nsugar\n"
```

I would like to find all ingredient lines and remove whitespaces and linebreaks

**2 dl. flour** and **4 cups of sugar**

My approach so far is to the following.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\d]+[\\s\\w\\.]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(Result);

while(m.find()) {
  // This is where i need help to remove those pesky whitespaces
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code should work for you:

```
String sample = "\n    \n   2 \n      \n  \ndl. \n \n    \n flour\n\n     \n 4   \n    \n cups of    \n\nsugar\n";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sample);
sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb, " ");
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println("Final: [" + sb.toString().trim() + ']');
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Final: [2 dl. flour 4 cups of sugar]
```

Comment: Your solution is just what im after, i will try it tomorrow. By the way, \n is included in \s, so you only need [\\s]+ in your pattern

Comment: Why not use `replaceAll()` like everyone else did?

Comment: Yes could have used `replaceAll()` as well, but OP was trying to do it using Pattern/Matcher Classes so wrote code using that.

Comment: Actually, the reason i use the pattern/matcher is becuase the string contains other stuff as well, but thats the actual recipe. I just want format the ingredients so they can be presented in a nice list.

Answer (score 4):

`sample = sample.replaceAll("[\\n ]+", " ").trim();`

Output:

`2 dl. flour 4 cups of sugar`

With no spaces in the beginning, and no spaces at the end.

It first replaces all spaces and newlines with a single space, and then trims of the extra space from the begging / end.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will work for you:

```
String test = "\n    \n   2 \n      \n  \ndl. \n \n    \n flour\n\n     \n 4   \n    \n cups of    \n\nsugar\n";

/* convert all sequences of whitespace into a single space, and trim the ends */
test = test.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that the `\n` are not actual line feed, but it also works with `linefeeds`.
This should work fine :

`test=test.replaceAll ("(?:\\s|\\\n)+"," ");`

In case there is no `textual \n` it can be simpler:

`test=test.replaceAll ("\\s+"," ");`

An you need to trim the leading/trailing spaces.

I use the RegexBuddy tool to check any single regex, very handy in so many languages.

Comment: To match the literal sequence `\n` (backslash + 'n'), you would need *four* backslashes in the regex (`\\\\n`), not three.  But it's pretty clear the OP is really trying to match linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the standard [String.replaceAll(String, String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  The first parameter will take your pattern, the second will take an empty string.

Comment: Thats where i need the regex variables which i dont really know how to use.
Let me examplify:

my pattern matches "\n    \n   2 \n      \n  \ndl. \n \n    \n flour\n\n     \n" and i would like to replace that with "2 dl. flour". my question here is how do i extract the information from the matched substring?

Comment: @Flexo, see my reply, it does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/^\s+//s
s/\s+$//s
s/(\s+)/ /s
```

Run those three substitutions (replacing leading whitespace with nothing, replace trailing whitespace with nothing, replace multiple whitespace with a space.